# I have a problem with SQLite in android apk file

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-studio

When I run my project from android studio to a device all works well and sqlite reads and writes all the data i want it to...but when I generate an APK SQLite doesn't work at all and I don't get any data, what could be the problem?

Edit:
I have used the command below to use my database and the database works in the apk and is created as you can see

[image]

and to update a certain element I use:

`String s = "UPDATE data SET Username='"+userT+"'";
                    database.execSQL ( s );`

Comment: after installing the apk to your mobile, did you try to see the .sqlite file not created using [device file explorer](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/device-file-explorer), add more details.

Comment: @josepraveen I have updated my question now if you can help please ^_^, and yes the device file explorer shows the db is created but just the values aren't added/updated

Comment: Either pull those temp files (shm, wal) as well, or close your database to have the database file be written to.